# How do I make this intrusive list thread safe?

Tags: c++, thread-safety

I am attempting to implement a "signals and slots" mechanism (think something similar to Qt) that is implemented using intrusive linked lists (to reduce the number of dynamic memory allocations required compared to, for example, using std::list).

The basic architecture consists of three classes: the signal class, the slot class, and the connection class.  If either the slot class or signal class is destroyed, the associated "connection" needs to be broken by a) removing the connection from the signal/slot's list and b) deleting the connection object.

I was able to put together some simplified example code which works as expected. Now, I am trying to figure out how to make it thread safe.

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <functional>
#include <mutex>

class A;
class B;

class Node
{
public:
    using Fn = void(B::*)();

public:
    Node(A* a, B* b, Fn fn) : a(a), b(b), fn(fn) {}
    ~Node();

    void foo()
    {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
        (b->*fn)();
    }

    A* a;
    B* b;

    Fn fn = nullptr;

    std::shared_ptr<Node> nextA = nullptr;
    std::shared_ptr<Node> nextB = nullptr;
};

class A
{
public:
    A();
    ~A();

    void add(std::shared_ptr<Node> n)
    {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;

        n->nextA = std::move(list_);
        list_ = std::move(n);
    }

    void remove(Node* nToRemove)
    {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;

        std::shared_ptr<Node> prev = nullptr;
        for (auto n = list_; n != nullptr; n = n->nextA)
        {
            if (n.get() == nToRemove)
            {
                if (prev == nullptr)
                {
                    list_ = n->nextA;
                }
                else
                {
                    prev->nextA = n->nextA;
                }
                
                break;
            }

            prev = n;
        }
    }

    void foo()
    {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
        for (auto n = list_; n != nullptr; n = n->nextA)
        {
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
            n->foo();
        }
    }

private:
    std::shared_ptr<Node> list_;
};

class B
{
public:
    B();
    ~B();

    void add(std::shared_ptr<Node> n)
    {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;

        n->nextB = std::move(list_);
        list_ = std::move(n);
    }

    void remove(Node* nToRemove)
    {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;

        std::shared_ptr<Node> prev = nullptr;
        for (auto n = list_; n != nullptr; n = n->nextB)
        {
            if (n.get() == nToRemove)
            {
                if (prev == nullptr)
                {
                    list_ = n->nextB;
                }
                else
                {
                    prev->nextB = n->nextB;
                }
                
                break;
            }

            prev = n;
        }
    }

    void foo()
    {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    }

    void bar()
    {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    }

private:
    std::shared_ptr<Node> list_;
};

Node::~Node()
{
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
}

A::A()
{
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
}

A::~A()
{
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;

    //"Notify" B to remove nodes
    for (auto n = list_; n != nullptr; n = n->nextA)
    {
        n->b->remove(n.get());
    }
}

B::B()
{
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
}

B::~B()
{
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;

    //"Notify" A to remove nodes
    for (auto n = list_; n != nullptr; n = n->nextB)
    {
        n->a->remove(n.get());
    }
}

void connect(A& a, B& b, Node::Fn fn)
{
    auto c = std::make_shared<Node>(std::addressof(a), std::addressof(b), fn);
    a.add(c);
    b.add(c);
}

int main()
{
    A a;

    std::thread t1([](A& a){
        B b;
        //connect(a, b, &B::foo);
        connect(a, b, &B::bar);
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    }, std::reference_wrapper<A>{a});

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));

    a.foo();

    t1.join();
}
```

The additional sleep_for statements are added to force out of order execution.  Currently, the output of the code is:

```
A::A()
B::B()
void A::add(std::shared_ptr<Node>)
void B::add(std::shared_ptr<Node>)
void A::foo()
B::~B()
void A::remove(Node*)
void Node::foo()
void B::bar()
Node::~Node()
A::~A()
```

As you can see, `B::bar()` ends up getting called after the instance of `B` is destroyed (this would cause a crash if the function were less trivial).

I have attempted to use mutexes to protect the structures but I am having difficulty because the data structure (linked list) is embedded with with data itself.  The connection cannot be destroyed (and thus `A` and `B` cannot be destroyed) whilst it is "being used" (i.e., while `Node::foo()` is being called).  But it cannot be used if either `A` or `B` are being destroyed.

Comment: Learn about std::thread/std::mutex/std::scoped_lock. Try to avoid leaking Nodes from your datastructure (they should be internal to something else). And in general I would advice you to implement signal slots in terms of a std::vector<std::function<retval_t>(args_t...)>. The whole construct with `Nodes` is not necessary. Then you must also make sure that your subcription list cannot change while you are calling "slots" etc.. etc...

Comment: Also, Boost [Signals2](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_84_0/doc/html/signals2.html) is a signals & slots implementation that you may find interesting.  (Signals2 is for C++11 and later.  The earlier Signals was for C++98.  Kind of like Catch2 (C++11 &c) and Catch (C++98).)

Comment: @Eljay I stopped using boost signals2, it is not fully threadsafe. It is not possible to change subscriptions while it is also calling slots.

Comment: Why do you need the list of registrations to be thread safe? The event emitter call from another thread would require the callback state to be thread safe as well, and that creates the risk of race conditions. The alternative is to pass messages between threads and never share state, so that no race conditions are possible by design.

Comment: @Eljay I took a look at Boost Signals2 while writing this question.  Reading through their implementation and design decisions was really insightful.  My main problem is, their implementation is pretty heavy (lost of dynamic allocations, deep list copying, etc...).  My goal is to be able to use this on a more resource-constrained/embedded system (thus why I am trying to limit my dynamic allocations).

Comment: Good to know.  I was suggesting **Signals2** as something that may be suitable out-of-the-box (but from Pepijn's comments, the threading issue may be a deal breaker — my project's usage is not cross-thread).  Or at least as an example of how they did it for inspiration, including what kind of surface public API they exposed for users.  Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of the direction I would take, using building blocks available in the standard library (so no datastructures of my own, like Node classes)

```
#include <functional>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <mutex>
#include <iostream>

namespace details
{

// internal callback to remove a subscription from the signal
struct unreg_signal_itf
{
     virtual ~unreg_signal_itf() = default;
     virtual void unregister(std::size_t slot_id) = 0;
};


// a raii object representing an active registration
// deleting this object will unregister the callback
struct registration_t
{
    unreg_signal_itf& signal;
    std::size_t id;

    ~registration_t()
    {
        signal.unregister(id);
    }
};
}

template<typename... args_t>
class signal_t : 
    public details::unreg_signal_itf // internal plumbing for RAII registration object
{
public:

    ~signal_t()
    {
        // do not destruct signal_t while
        // it is calling callbacks or updating m_slots!
        std::scoped_lock lock{m_mtx};
    }

    // subscribe a callback function
    auto subscribe(std::function<void(args_t...)> slot)
    {
        // we are going to update m_slots
        // make that threadsafe
        std::scoped_lock lock{m_mtx};
        m_slots[++m_slot_id] = slot;
        return details::registration_t{*this,m_slot_id};
    }

    // Call all callbacks with specified set of arguments
    void operator()(args_t&&... args)
    {
        // while calling other classes
        // ensure the m_slots variable cannot be changed.
        // this is for thread safety
        std::scoped_lock lock{m_mtx};

        // structured binding to iterate over 
        // all registered callbacks
        for(const auto& [id,slot] : m_slots)
        {
            slot(std::forward<args_t>(args)...);
        }
    }

private:
    // only to be called by a registration_t object
    // can be made private so it cannot be misused
    // by other clients (at least not easily)
    void unregister(std::size_t id) override
    {
        std::scoped_lock lock{m_mtx};
        auto it = m_slots.find(id);
        m_slots.erase(it);
    }

    std::size_t m_slot_id{0ul};
    std::mutex m_mtx;

    // use a map to link subscription identifiers to slots
    // this will make it easy to unregister callbacks
    // without resorting to pointers etc.
    std::unordered_map<std::size_t,std::function<void(args_t...)>> m_slots;
};


int main()
{
    signal_t<int> signal;

    // scope to test duration of subscription
    {
        // with std::function approach 
        // you can subscribe a lot of things like lambda expressions
        auto subscription = signal.subscribe([](int value){ std::cout << value << "\n"; });

        signal(42); // will resutl in callback being called

        // subscription will go out of scope here
        // so callback will be removed from the signal here.
    }

    // subscription has expired so
    // the callback function will no longer be called
    signal(42);

}
```

Comment: I like using a `std::size_t` for the unregistering "coat check token" rather than pointers.